# 'FromHeaderAttribute' is not an attribute class

Tags: asp.net-web-api, attributes, model-binding

Having pulled this codebase:

https://github.com/RedRiverSoftware/FromHeaderAttribute

after reading this:

https://river.red/binding-to-and-validating-http-headers-with-web-api-2/

I am trying to change this:

```
public IHttpActionResult EchoHeaders([RedRiver.FromHead.FromHeader]StandardHeaders headers)
```

to this:

```
public IHttpActionResult EchoHeaders([FromHeader]StandardHeaders headers)
```

Obviously, I needed to add this to the top of the controller class:

```
using FromHeaderAttribute.Sample.Models;
```

But I am getting this error:

```
'FromHeaderAttribute' is not an attribute class.
```

However, looking at the code (which I have not changed) the '`FromHeaderAttribute`' class clearly inherits '`ParameterBindingAttribute`' which inherits '`System.Attribute`'.

What am I missing to be able to define attributes which can be used as parameter attributes without specifying their whole namespace - just like attributes such as '`FromUri`' and '`FromBody`'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that naming a class 'FromHeader' and trying to use it as a parameter attribute will not get recognised. I've tried this with a number of different combinations of file, class and namespace names and it just doesn't work. The attribute class name must be anything except FromHeader.